# Disable Cascade Delete EF6

Tags: ef-code-first, entity, entity-framework-6, cascade

I'm trying to disable cascade delete using EF6 code-first.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}
```

When I try to delete a record in table I get an error

> "The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this
>   key still exist. [ Foreign key constraint name =
>   FK_dbo.OperatorActivity_dbo.Operator_OperatorId ]"

My models

```
public class OperatorActivity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool Synched { get; set; }

    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
    public Guid StationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
    public Guid OperatorId { get; set; }
}

public class Operator
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

    public virtual  Network Network { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OperatorActivity> Activities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Refill> Refills { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

How can I disable cascade delete?

Comment: You are trying to remove the main table row first, while you should first delete associated rows.

Comment: I'm trying to delete "Operator" table fist. I need to delete only Operator table and keep all data in OperatorActivity table.

Comment: It is not possible because of foreign key relationship. `drop foreign key FK_dbo.OperatorActivity_dbo.Operator_OperatorId ` in database

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not logical to remove referenced (parent) rows while keeping child rows, to be allowed to do that, you should drop the foreign key constraint.

In **MySQL** database run:

```
alter table OperatorActivity drop 
foreign key FK_dbo.OperatorActivity_dbo.Operator_OperatorId
```

In **SQL Server**:

```
alter table OperatorActivity drop 
constraint FK_dbo.OperatorActivity_dbo.Operator_OperatorId
```